# Parent child div removechild() unable to work

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a parent div and a child div.
here is the
 **html**

```
<div id="parent">Parent

    <div id="child">Child Div</div>
</div>
```

The Js

```
var parent = document.createElement("parent");
var childDiv = document.createElement("child");
parent.removeChild(childDiv);
```

But it does not remove the child.
Please tell me where am i doing it wrong.
Thanks

Comment: Don't let @NotoriousPet0 get to you Marc!  Your question was appropriate; I definitely recommend checking out the Mozilla Developer Network as a great resource for learning more.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/

Comment: Googling "javascript createElement" gets you the answer to this question in less than 2 minutes.    I don't think people should post on here before they spend at least 2 minutes trying to figure it out on their own.  Apparently that is not the opinion of anyone else on here, including mods.. so I dunno.   I guess I should just ignore bad questions and move on.  I thought the point of voting etc.. was to have community moderation of content on SO.  Apparently I don't understand this site.

Comment: @NotoriousPet0 that's the thing: you knew to google about createElement!  Marc had no idea that createElement wasn't incorrect, he thought the issue was with removeChild.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) actually creates new HTML elements -- that is not the same as retrieving elements that already exist.

To get a reference to your HTML elements, use [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) instead.

Try this:

```
var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
var childDiv = document.getElementById("child");
parent.removeChild(childDiv);
```

Comment: Eh, he just used the wrong method and asked a question because it wasn't behaving as expected.  I wasn't offended by it...  (also.. did you downvote my answer for some reason..?  I don't mind but, sheish, harsh!)

Comment: Yeah, I can't remember why, maybe it was when I misunderstood the question.  It's only -2 but I'll take it off if it helps you out.     I guess I am a bit harsh. I just got a stern message from mods over my comments on this question. (you have to edit your answer before it will let me removed the downvote)

Comment: No worries on the vote at all!  Anyway, sounds like you got the picture but in general remember SO is for coders of ALL level; it can be really daunting for people who are just trying to learn so it's on us veterans to be welcoming and understanding.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure my communication skills could use some work on all fronts.  Pretty typical of coders to be anti-social as far as I've seen, but I guess if your on here with the intention of helping, it goes without saying you need to put the bad attitude aside and at least pretend to be nice. haha :)